Executing python function remotely
I am trying to make a simple script to run python functions on another computer from my computer, for example I have a function called command_1(). Which prints “hi” in terminal, I want to run this function on another computer based on input on my computer, so like I run some kind of command in terminal which executes the python function on a different computer.
I don’t know where to start so I didn’t try anything, I’m kinda new to python.
Just a quick note:
I won’t be running this on a server, there is a thing for that, I want to run it on another computer
I am using a Mac with an intel chip and running python3 and have macOS target machine would preferably be any computer but if it can only be for one then a MacBook running macOS with intel chip.
Thank you.

A server is also another computer. What do you consider to be the difference?

@mkrieger1 I mean, there is another post on how to do that, but I don’t have like an actual server, it’s supposed to be a thing where when they download a file, I can remotely execute python commands on their computer. So I can’t set it as a server or change any settings.

There's nothing built-in that would allow this, it would be an incredible security hole. You have to run software on the target computer that allows it to receive python code and execute it. The easiest way would be to run a Flask server on the target.

Are you trying to open a massive security hole? To do this without creating a big security problem would require significant effort and plenty of python knowledge. Having said that, it can be done…
